# Database insert not working on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I'm doing an Android application and I have a database. I'm able to do queries but the inserts don't seem to be working. I have a table named profile with the fields "id", "name" and "original".

This is the method:

```
public void addProfile(String name)
{       
myDataBase.rawQuery("INSERT INTO profile(name, original) values('"+name+"', '0')", null);       
}
```

And what I'm doing:

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(activity);

```
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    for(Profile p : profiles){
        myDbHelper.addProfile(p.getName());
        System.out.println("Commiting profile "+ p.getName());
```

In LogCat it correctly appears "Commiting profile test".

I'm opening the database with:

```
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

I've searched everywhere for the erro and I can't seem to find it. Is it because I have an "id" instead of "_id" on the table? Wouldn't that only affect the SELECTs? In my Selects I use select id as _id but in insert I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not allowed to use rawQuery to insert data. You should use [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Or to make life even easier, [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: sure, for simple inserts it is preferred method.

Comment: Thank you so much, that just saved me hours of research =)